# Mysql Can I make an update with join

Tags: mysql, join, updates

I have a database with several tables and all my queries work but I would like to had a new one and can't succeed to make it working.
Two tables 'vins' and 'producteurs'with a foreign key IDproducteur in my 'vins' table.
I need to update the 'vins'table from an excel source where the data are not always written corectly and need to change the stock value for some records of the 'vins' table.The p.nomproducteur and V.annee  and v.nom are parameters but for test I put hard values.
 My Query is the following:

```
UPDATE vins AS v 
JOIN producteurs p  
ON ( p.IDproducteur = v.IDproducteur AND p.nomproducteur LIKE "Charles" )
SET stock = 10
WHERE v.nom LIKE "Symphonie" AND v.annee = 2013
```

I have two records where the producteur is "Charles" and V.nom is Symphonie one withe annee = 2010 and one with 2013. I got no error in phpMyadmin but there is no results to my Query even by changing some command order. 
Is what I want  impossible to do?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the condition `p.nomproducteur LIKE "Charles"` in the WHERE clause:

```
UPDATE vins v 
JOIN producteurs p ON p.IDproducteur = v.IDproducteur 
SET stock = 10
WHERE 
  v.nom = "Symphonie" AND v.annee = 2013 AND p.nomproducteur = "Charles"
```

Also there is no need for `LIKE` in this case, a simple `=` will do.

Comment: *"Also there is no need for LIKE in this case, a simple = will do."* Very true statement sometimes you would wish [MySQL string optimizers](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9HJEzULbdP2qTAf4sMPCNw/0) would be much smarter which know `LIKE "Charles"` is (in the most cases COLLATE exceptions not included) the same as `= "Charles"` same would count for using `REGEX "Charles"`  i would love to see the internal optimizing `= "Charles"` for those kind off queries.

Comment: It works, but I was thinking as a fool that LIKE could help me to cover case where the parameter was not really written as in the base. So I try with SOUNDS LIKE but we are in france and the soundex doesn't work so wel...

Comment: You can use LIKE, in cases where the parameter is part of the string: `LIKE '%Charles%'` and by default in MySql it's case insensitive. Find more here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html

Answer (score 0):

The update  based on JOIN is commonly used  in mysql  so be sure that your join and where condition really match the values  in your tables

```
UPDATE vins AS v 
INNER JOIN producteurs p ON  p.IDproducteur = v.IDproducteur 
SET v.stock = 10
WHERE v.nom =  "Symphonie" 
AND v.annee = 2013 
AND p.nomproducteur = "Charles"
```

and do the fact you are not filter for partial string use = instead  of like